# Error in web page "This site cant' be reached"

Tags: php

My PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>
    <?php
    echo "this is ";
    echo "title";
    ?>
  </title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I am getting

> This site can't be reached

In my Chrome browser when I am writing:

```
localhost/phpTutorial/comment.php
```

Here `phpTutorial` is the folder where all PHP files are stored and PHP tutorial is made inside `htdocs` of `XAMPP` folder.

Location description:-

```
C:->XAMPP->htdocs->phpTutorial->comment.php
```

The same URL/PHP files was running smoothly some time before but now it is not running.

Please solve my issue and suggest what is wrong in this in a beginner friendly way.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in your code kindly check your xampp is running or not problem in your xampp  restart `apache` and `mysql`  or restart your system and start `apache` and `mysql` .

i hope you got your solution .